# Error while converting a frozen.pb file to tflite format

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

```
tflite_convert   --output_file=./graph.tflite   --graph_def_file=output_graph_frozen.pb   --input_arrays=IteratorV2 --output_arrays=linear/head/predictions/probabilities
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tflite_convert", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 503, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 499, in run_main
    _convert_tf1_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 193, in _convert_tf1_model
    output_data = converter.convert()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 898, in convert
    **converter_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 401, in toco_convert_impl
    input_tensors, output_tensors, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 304, in build_toco_convert_protos
    input_tensor.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/util.py", line 58, in convert_dtype_to_tflite_type
    raise ValueError("Unsupported tf.dtype {0}".format(tf_dtype))
ValueError: Unsupported tf.dtype

Comment: Does tflite support models with .csv data input?

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose for setting the "input_arrays" and "output_arrays"?

In the most simple case, you can just do

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

as documented at https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api.